# Does market maker buy when nobody else is buying and sell when nobody else is selling?

Tags: stock-exchanges, markets

In this investopedia [article](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/trading/06/level2quotes.asp) , they say:

> Market Makers (MM) - These are the players who provide liquidity in
>   the marketplace. This means that they are required to buy when nobody
>   else is buying and sell when nobody else is selling. They make the
>   market.

I thought when nobody wants to buy, the demand keeps dropping, so prices keep dropping until it hits a circuit breaker. Is the above statement exaggerated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Market Makers are generally not involved in making a market for illiquid shares. Market Makers are there to make a market for derivatives - for example for options or warrants.

If a bid price has been entered for what is considered a fair market price (based on the price of the underlying security) for an option, for example, but there is no matching ask price anywhere near this fair market price, then this is where the Market Maker will come in and make the market for that bid price.